# C# & EF : how to get the new records comparing compound key with three columns?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a table `Table1` that has a key made up of three columns, field1, field2 and field3.

I send to server my client list of records.

How can I get the new records from the server?

I have this:

```
var field1ExistInClient = listClientData.Select(d => d.field1);

List<Table1> newRecords = appDb.Table1.Where(d => !field1ExistInClient.Contains(d.field1)).ToList();
```

In this case I get all the new field1, but if a field1 exist but have a variation in field2 and field3, I will not be able to get that records.

Just remember the key is made up from three columns:

```
key = field1 + field2 + field3;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using NOT?

Comment: Because I want only the new records, the ones that the client don't have.

Answer (score 0):

You can check field2 and field3 in the same way you checked field1, just return the records if any of the fields are not contained in your list

```
var field1ExistInClient = listClientData.Select(d => d.field1);
var field2ExistInClient = listClientData.Select(d => d.field2);
var field2ExistInClient = listClientData.Select(d => d.field3);
    
List<Table1> newRecords = appDb.Table1.Where(d => 
    !field1ExistInClient.Contains(d.field1)
    || !field2ExistInClient.Contains(d.field2)
    || !field3ExistInClient.Contains(d.field3)
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, but in that case field2 may be the same that others filed1 or field3 that don't correspond to the specific record that is new.

Comment: Maybe I should loop all the client records and compare each one with all the records of the server, but that's gonna have high cost of resources.